# Is there a name for negating a condition in an if-else block?

Tags: coding-style

I recently reviewed code that read as follows:

```
if (!condition) {
  do_something();
} else {
  do_something_else();
}
```

In other words, in the if statement we checked that a condition was false, and ran one of two functions depending on its truth value.

I thought this was a confusing style, and recommended that the condition be checked as-is, and the if and else blocks be switched. I couldn't find a name for this "negated condition in if-else" pattern, however. Is there an existing name for this pattern?

Comment: Yes, it's called NOT.  `if not condition then do_something() else do_something_else()`.  It's perfectly readable in context.  For example: `if not end of file then read some more data`.

Comment: It's called "negating a condition." Were you looking for something else?

Comment: I was hoping it had a cute name, along the lines of "Yoda conditions" being conditions where the constant is listed before the variable in a comparison. I was hoping for a name so that I could search on Google and see what people think of the pattern.

Comment: Why would you rely on the subjective opinions of random strangers on the internet (i.e. "what other people think") to make up your own mind?

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts, especially those involving operator overloading, expressions like `foo!=bar` and `!(foo==bar)` might have different corner-case behavior.  Even when not using operator overloading, the natural meaning for the former may be "foo has a value which is something other than bar's value", as distinct from "foo doesn't have the same value as bar".

Further, the code pattern:

```
if (condition1)
{
  if (condition2)
    action1;
  else
    action2;
}
else
  action3;
```

will often be harder to read than:

```
if (!condition1)
  action3;
else if (condition2)
  action1;
else
  action2;
```

despite the necessity of inverting the first condition.  I don't think there's a particular name for that pattern, but it's hardly unusual.

Comment: Good point, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko: The author thought the style was confusing, and asked if there was a name.  I related two reasons that kind of code might be used [the author's example didn't say anything about the form of 'condition' or the contents of either branch, so it's unclear which situation if either might apply], and also said I'm unaware of a specific name for such a construct.  Unless someone has given the construct a name I don't know about, nobody would be able to offer a better answer regarding its name.

Comment: Oh. I see. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks for the clarification.